# iOS - UIActivityViewController's items show incorrect position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying implement a function that can share a URL link to other app via UIActivityViewController. It works very well on most times. However, sometime it show the items in weird position like following picture.
[image]

```
  if (!share_Text) {
    return;
}

NSURL *share_Url = [NSURL URLWithString:share_Text];

if(shareImage) {
    activityItems = @[ share_Url?share_Url:share_Text,
                       shareImage ];
}
else {
    activityItems = @[ share_Url?share_Url:share_Text ];
}

NSMutableArray *activityApp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems
                                  applicationActivities:activityApp];

activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList];

if(NSClassFromString(@"UIPopoverPresentationController")) {
    activityVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = controller.view;
}

if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:(@selector(setCompletionWithItemsHandler:))]){
    [activityVC setCompletionWithItemsHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {
        if(completeFunc) completeFunc(activityType, completed, activityError);
    }];
}else{
    [activityVC setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
        if(completeFunc) completeFunc(activityType, completed, nil);
    }];
}

[controller presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I have already tried to search some solution on the internet, but I don't know what keyword should I use. I'm so appreciate If anyone knows how to solve this problem or what causes this problem. Thanks!

Comment: you need to share image and text?

Comment: @Jigar  encountered this problem when I only shared NSURL.